# How can I solve first order differential quation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Which method should I use to solve this equation ?

$$\left(x-1\right)\frac{dy}{dx}-x\left(4x+5\right)+4\left(2x+1\right)y\:-\:4y^2\:=\:0 $$

I tried using substitution method. please give me a hint.

Comment: Hint: This is a Riccati type equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Riccati equation is easy to solve if a particular solution is known. Often, the main difficulty is to find a particular solution. But, since it is probably an exercise for student, probably a particular solution of very simple form exists. This draw to try some simple elementary functions, for example a linear function $\:y=ax+b\:$. This trial is successful : By easy identification, one find $\:a=1\:$ and $_\:b=\frac{1}{2}\:$

Then, following the usual method of change of function :
$$y(x)=u(x)+x+\frac{1}{2}$$
puting it into the ODE, and after simplification :
$$(x-1)u'=4u^2$$
It is easy to solve this separable ODE :
$$u=-\frac{1}{4\ln(x-1)+c}$$
$$y=x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4\ln(x-1)+c}$$

Comment: You have used  $$ y(x)= u(x)+x+1/2 $$, what will be the answer if I take the function as $$ y(x)= 1/u(x)+x+1/2 $$ ?

Comment: The final result will be exactly the same. But take care of a possible confusion : do not use the same symbol for two different functions. So, better let $$y(x)=1/v(x)+x+1/2$$ . Solving  the transformed ODE will give $$v(x)=4\ln(x-1)+c$$.